# How to use function inside other function?

Tags: javascript, html

I dont know how to make function 'bot_turn' work after function 'player_turn'

Maybe there are some problems with two 'while' functions

```js
var asasa = 0;
var lal = -1;
var end_game = 0;
var asass = 0
asasa = 0;

function player_turn() {

  if (document.getElementById('tables1').className == 'one' & asasa == 1) {
    document.getElementById('tables1').className = 'none'
    alert("Bot turn")
    end_game = end_game + 1;
    bot_turn()
  } else if (document.getElementById('tables2').className == 'two' && asasa == 2) {
    document.getElementById('tables2').className = 'none'
    alert("Bot turn")
    end_game = end_game + 1;
    bot_turn()
  } else if (document.getElementById('tables3').className == 'three' && asasa == 3) {
    document.getElementById('tables3').className = 'none'
    alert("Bot turn")
    end_game = end_game + 1;
    bot_turn()
  } else if (document.getElementById('tables4').className == 'four' && asasa == 4) {
    document.getElementById('tables4').className = 'none'
    alert("Bot turn")
    end_game = end_game + 1;
    bot_turn()
  } else if (document.getElementById('tables5').className == 'five' && asasa == 5) {
    document.getElementById('tables5').className = 'none'
    alert("Bot turn")
    end_game = end_game + 1;
    bot_turn()
  } else if (document.getElementById('tables6').className == 'six' && asasa == 6) {
    document.getElementById('tables6').className = 'none'
    alert("Bot turn")
    end_game = end_game + 1;
    bot_turn()
  } else if (document.getElementById('tables7').className == 'seven' && asasa == 7) {
    document.getElementById('tables7').className = 'none'
    alert("Bot turn")
    end_game = end_game + 1;
    bot_turn()
  } else if (document.getElementById('tables8').className == 'eight' && asasa == 8) {
    document.getElementById('tables8').className = 'none'
    alert("Bot turn")
    end_game = end_game + 1;
    bot_turn()
  } else if (document.getElementById('tables9').className == 'nine' && asasa == 9) {
    document.getElementById('tables9').className = 'none'
    alert("Bot turn")
    end_game = end_game + 1;
    bot_turn()
  }
  console.log(asasa)
}

var randomik = 0;

function bot_turn() {
  while (asass = 0) {
    lal = 0
    while (lal = 0) {
      randomik = Math.floor((Math.random() * 9) + 1);
      console.log(randomik)
      if (randomik == 1) {
        if (document.getElementById('tables1').className == 'one') {
          document.getElementById('tables1').className = 'none'
          document.getElementById('tables1').style.backgroundColor = '#FF2400'
          alert("Player turn")
          lal = 1
          end_game += 1
        }
      } else if (randomik == 2) {
        if (document.getElementById('tables2').className == 'two') {
          document.getElementById('tables2').className = 'none'
          document.getElementById('tables2').style.backgroundColor = '#FF2400'
          alert("Player turn")
          lal = 1;
          end_game += 1
        }
      } else if (randomik == 3) {
        if (document.getElementById('tables3').className == 'three') {
          document.getElementById('tables3').className = 'none'
          document.getElementById('tables3').style.backgroundColor = '#FF2400'
          alert("Player turn")
          lal = 1;
          end_game += 1
        }
      } else if (randomik == 4) {
        if (document.getElementById('tables4').className == 'four') {
          document.getElementById('tables4').className = 'none'
          document.getElementById('tables4').style.backgroundColor = '#FF2400'
          alert("Player turn")
          lal = 1;
          end_game += 1
        }
      } else if (randomik == 5) {
        if (document.getElementById('tables5').className == 'five') {
          document.getElementById('tables5').className = 'none'
          document.getElementById('tables5').style.backgroundColor = '#FF2400'
          alert("Player turn")
          lal = 1;
          end_game += 1
        }
      } else if (randomik == 6) {
        if (document.getElementById('tables6').className == 'six') {
          document.getElementById('tables6').className = 'none'
          document.getElementById('tables6').style.backgroundColor = '#FF2400'
          alert("Player turn")
          lal = 1;
          end_game += 1
        }
      } else if (randomik == 7) {
        if (document.getElementById('tables7').className == 'seven') {
          document.getElementById('tables7').className = 'none'
          document.getElementById('tables7').style.backgroundColor = '#FF2400'
          alert("Player turn")
          lal = 1;
          end_game += 1
        }
      } else if (randomik == 8) {
        if (document.getElementById('tables8').className == 'eight') {
          document.getElementById('tables8').className = 'none'
          document.getElementById('tables8').style.backgroundColor = '#FF2400'
          alert("Player turn")
          lal = 1;
          end_game += 1
        }
      } else if (randomik == 9) {
        if (document.getElementById('tables9').className == 'nine') {
          document.getElementById('tables9').className = 'none'
          document.getElementById('tables9').style.backgroundColor = '#FF2400'
          alert("Player turn")
          lal = 1;
          end_game += 1
        }
      } else if (end_game == 9) {
        asass = 1
        alert('It works!')
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Tic Tac Toe</title>
</head>

<body>
  <table border='1px' width='500px' height='500px' align="center">
    <tr>
      <td id='tables1' class="one" style="font-size: 50px; text-align:center;" onclick="this.style.backgroundColor = '#045d99';asasa=1; player_turn(); "></td>
      <td id='tables2' class="two" style="font-size: 50px; text-align:center;" onclick="this.style.backgroundColor = '#045d99';asasa=2; player_turn();"></td>
      <td id='tables3' class="three" style="font-size: 50px; text-align:center;" onclick="this.style.backgroundColor = '#045d99';asasa=3; player_turn();"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr style='border-color: red'>
      <td id='tables4' class="four" style="font-size: 50px; text-align:center;" onclick="this.style.backgroundColor = '#045d99';asasa=4; player_turn(); "></td>
      <td id='tables5' class="five" style="font-size: 50px; text-align:center;" onclick="this.style.backgroundColor = '#045d99';asasa=5; player_turn();"></td>
      <td id='tables6' class="six" style="font-size: 50px; text-align:center;" onclick="this.style.backgroundColor = '#045d99';asasa=6; player_turn();"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr style='border-color: red'>
      <td id='tables7' class="seven" style="font-size: 50px; text-align:center;" onclick="this.style.backgroundColor = '#045d99';asasa=7; player_turn();"></td>
      <td id='tables8' class="eight" style="font-size: 50px; text-align:center;" onclick="this.style.backgroundColor = '#045d99';asasa=8; player_turn();"></td>
      <td id='tables9' class="nine" style="font-size: 50px; text-align:center;" onclick="this.style.backgroundColor = '#045d99';asasa=9; player_turn();"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
```

When i click bot must choose another cell where i hadnt click and paint it in red. When all cells are painted alert "It works!" should appear and random numbers in consol must stop generating.

Comment: Hello! Coud you provide a [Minimal Complete and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example, please? Going through all your code may be hard.

Comment: for starters `asass=0` is an assignment operation and returns `0`, meaning `while(asass=0){}` assigns `0` to `asass`, returns the zero, and the loop is not entered, since it is interpretted as `while(false){}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few things, First off as mentioned in the comments `asass=0` is an assignment operation not a comparison operation, it should be `asass==0`.

By taking away the outer while loop in the `bot_turn()` function and changing the inner while loop to an if statement I got a working version. The only issue is when the bot chooses a number which has already been selected, in that case the bot will never execute his turn, so you need to add an array to store the chosen numbers and make sure the bot chooses one not in that array.

Below is a working snippet (with alerts removed).

```js
var asasa = 0;
var lal = -1;
var end_game = 0;
var asass = 0
asasa = 0;
guessArr = []

function player_turn() {
  if (end_game > 8) {
    asass = 0
    alert('It works!')
    return;
  }
  if (guessArr.includes(asasa)) {
    player_turn()
    console.log("you already guessed this")
  } else {
    guessArr.push(asasa)

    if (document.getElementById('tables1').className == 'one' & asasa == 1) {
      document.getElementById('tables1').className = 'none'
      end_game = end_game + 1;
      bot_turn()
    } else if (document.getElementById('tables2').className == 'two' && asasa == 2) {
      document.getElementById('tables2').className = 'none'
      end_game = end_game + 1;
      bot_turn()
    } else if (document.getElementById('tables3').className == 'three' && asasa == 3) {
      document.getElementById('tables3').className = 'none'
      end_game = end_game + 1;
      bot_turn()
    } else if (document.getElementById('tables4').className == 'four' && asasa == 4) {
      document.getElementById('tables4').className = 'none'
      end_game = end_game + 1;
      bot_turn()
    } else if (document.getElementById('tables5').className == 'five' && asasa == 5) {
      document.getElementById('tables5').className = 'none'
      end_game = end_game + 1;
      bot_turn()
    } else if (document.getElementById('tables6').className == 'six' && asasa == 6) {
      document.getElementById('tables6').className = 'none'
      end_game = end_game + 1;
      bot_turn()
    } else if (document.getElementById('tables7').className == 'seven' && asasa == 7) {
      document.getElementById('tables7').className = 'none'
      end_game = end_game + 1;
      bot_turn()
    } else if (document.getElementById('tables8').className == 'eight' && asasa == 8) {
      document.getElementById('tables8').className = 'none'
      end_game = end_game + 1;
      bot_turn()
    } else if (document.getElementById('tables9').className == 'nine' && asasa == 9) {
      document.getElementById('tables9').className = 'none'
      end_game = end_game + 1;
      bot_turn()
    }
    console.log(asasa)
  }
}

var randomik = 0;

function bot_turn() {
  if (end_game > 8) {
    asass = 0
    alert('It works!')
    return;
  }
  lal = 0
  if (lal == 0) {
    randomik = Math.floor((Math.random() * 9) + 1);
    if (guessArr.includes(randomik)) {
      bot_turn()
      console.log("you already guessed this")
    } else {
      guessArr.push(randomik)
      console.log(randomik)
      if (randomik == 1) {
        if (document.getElementById('tables1').className == 'one') {
          document.getElementById('tables1').className = 'none'
          document.getElementById('tables1').style.backgroundColor = '#FF2400'
          lal = 1
          end_game += 1
        }
      } else if (randomik == 2) {
        if (document.getElementById('tables2').className == 'two') {
          document.getElementById('tables2').className = 'none'
          document.getElementById('tables2').style.backgroundColor = '#FF2400'
          lal = 1;
          end_game += 1
        }
      } else if (randomik == 3) {
        if (document.getElementById('tables3').className == 'three') {
          document.getElementById('tables3').className = 'none'
          document.getElementById('tables3').style.backgroundColor = '#FF2400'
          lal = 1;
          end_game += 1
        }
      } else if (randomik == 4) {
        if (document.getElementById('tables4').className == 'four') {
          document.getElementById('tables4').className = 'none'
          document.getElementById('tables4').style.backgroundColor = '#FF2400'
          lal = 1;
          end_game += 1
        }
      } else if (randomik == 5) {
        if (document.getElementById('tables5').className == 'five') {
          document.getElementById('tables5').className = 'none'
          document.getElementById('tables5').style.backgroundColor = '#FF2400'
          lal = 1;
          end_game += 1
        }
      } else if (randomik == 6) {
        if (document.getElementById('tables6').className == 'six') {
          document.getElementById('tables6').className = 'none'
          document.getElementById('tables6').style.backgroundColor = '#FF2400'
          lal = 1;
          end_game += 1
        }
      } else if (randomik == 7) {
        if (document.getElementById('tables7').className == 'seven') {
          document.getElementById('tables7').className = 'none'
          document.getElementById('tables7').style.backgroundColor = '#FF2400'
          lal = 1;
          end_game += 1
        }
      } else if (randomik == 8) {
        if (document.getElementById('tables8').className == 'eight') {
          document.getElementById('tables8').className = 'none'
          document.getElementById('tables8').style.backgroundColor = '#FF2400'
          lal = 1;
          end_game += 1
        }
      } else if (randomik == 9) {
        if (document.getElementById('tables9').className == 'nine') {
          document.getElementById('tables9').className = 'none'
          document.getElementById('tables9').style.backgroundColor = '#FF2400'
          lal = 1;
          end_game += 1
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Tic Tac Toe</title>
</head>

<body>
  <table border='1px' width='500px' height='500px' align="center">
    <tr>
      <td id='tables1' class="one" style="font-size: 50px; text-align:center;" onclick="this.style.backgroundColor = '#045d99';asasa=1; player_turn(); "></td>
      <td id='tables2' class="two" style="font-size: 50px; text-align:center;" onclick="this.style.backgroundColor = '#045d99';asasa=2; player_turn();"></td>
      <td id='tables3' class="three" style="font-size: 50px; text-align:center;" onclick="this.style.backgroundColor = '#045d99';asasa=3; player_turn();"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr style='border-color: red'>
      <td id='tables4' class="four" style="font-size: 50px; text-align:center;" onclick="this.style.backgroundColor = '#045d99';asasa=4; player_turn(); "></td>
      <td id='tables5' class="five" style="font-size: 50px; text-align:center;" onclick="this.style.backgroundColor = '#045d99';asasa=5; player_turn();"></td>
      <td id='tables6' class="six" style="font-size: 50px; text-align:center;" onclick="this.style.backgroundColor = '#045d99';asasa=6; player_turn();"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr style='border-color: red'>
      <td id='tables7' class="seven" style="font-size: 50px; text-align:center;" onclick="this.style.backgroundColor = '#045d99';asasa=7; player_turn();"></td>
      <td id='tables8' class="eight" style="font-size: 50px; text-align:center;" onclick="this.style.backgroundColor = '#045d99';asasa=8; player_turn();"></td>
      <td id='tables9' class="nine" style="font-size: 50px; text-align:center;" onclick="this.style.backgroundColor = '#045d99';asasa=9; player_turn();"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
```

Comment: it work but sometimes bot doesnt make a move because space is already painter and bot doesnt random one more time

Comment: You need to add a check to see if the box is already painted or number is already guessed before painting the box.

Comment: if (document.getElementById('tables4').className == 'four')

Comment: @HipHopReaper I edited my answer to be fully functional. You need to add a guess array and check if the current guess is in that array, if so let the user/bot pick again until they picked a number that hasn't been guessed. Let me know if this answer works for you.